# Code for adding people to shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to share a workbook with people whose emails are in cells(A1:A5).

Unfortunately, I haven't got the faintest clue on how to write this.

Seeing as I've been unable to find such code, I've got nothing to show for it.
All I've got is the condition that the workbook is indeed being shared.

```
Sub sharingIsCaring()

If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording the macro while doing the action, and taking the code from there?

Comment: Yes, I have. Nothing of importance gets recorded.